# how to use function from current file in required script

Tags: node.js

I have 2 files.
A.js

```
let test = require('./b');
test.run(2,4)

function fnCount(a,b){
 return a+b;
}
```

B.js

```
exports.run=async function (a,b){
  try{
    fnCount(a,b)
  }
  catch(err){
    throw err;
  }
}
```

I am getting reference error. fnCount is not defined. Any idea how to use function from file A in file B while B is required in file A ?

Basically what I have is that A.js is a template for all my scripts and b.js is my script that is build using function from A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the function in A.js to B.js as an argument in `require`, like this:

A.js:

```
let test = require('./b')(fnCount);
test.run(2, 4)

function fnCount(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

B.js:

```
module.exports = function(fnCount) {
  return {
    run: async function (a, b) {
      try {
        fnCount(a, b)
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hm I am getting TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Comment: My bad, forgot to add `module.` before `exports`. Thanks to @trixo for the fast correction (the code above works now).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an argument from **A.js**.The simplest way to do is.

```
let test = require('./b');
test.run(2,4,fnCount)

function fnCount(a,b){
 return a+b;
}
exports.run=async function (a,b,fnCount){
  try{
    fnCount(a,b);
  }
  catch(err){
    throw err;
  }
}
```